# Почему при разных способах AJAX запроса время ответа занимает разное время?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, requests

Почему при разных способах AJAX запроса время ответа занимает разное время?
при отправке запроса через NODE JS на сторонний сайт. время ответа занимает 2 секунды.
при отправке запроса через браузер около 500мс.

Comment: Браузер и Node запускаются на одной машине?

Comment: да, запускаются на 1

Comment: Через js в браузере отправляете?

Comment: так точно. обычный AJAX запрос.
в node js отправляю через модуль request.

Comment: А при отправке через сайт вы получаете полностью валидный результат? Может, также , в браузере запрос кешируется. Попробуйте выполнить его в приватной вкладке.

Answer (score 0):

Быть может, браузер кеширует соответствие домена ip-адресу и не делает dns lookup?
А может даже браузер соединился с сервером и с прошлого запроса не отсоединился, и тогда не тратит время на соединение?

А общем в любом случае я ставлю на то, что это какая-то браузерная оптимизация, которую можно и в nodejs сделать.